Нужна ли запятая перед "старше"?
Людей старше 80 лет в районе проживает немало.

Правильно:
Людей старше 80 лет в районе проживает немало.
Сравнить: Таких людей, старше 80 лет, в районе проживает немало.
Это несогласованное определение, выраженное сравнительной степенью прилагательного. Обособление возможно  при наличии предшествующего согласованного определения.
Розенталь:  § 18. Обособленные определения. Несогласованные определения
2. Несогласованное определение, выраженное оборотом с формой 
сравнительной степени прилагательного (часто определяемому 
существительному предшествует согласованное определение), 
обособляется: Сила, сильнее его воли, сбросила его оттуда 
(Т.); Короткая борода, немного темнее волос, слегка оттеняла 
губы и подбородок (А. К. Т.); Другая комната, почти вдвое 
больше, называлась залой (Ч.).

Но при тесной связи с существительным такое определение не 
обособляется: Зато в другое время не было человека 
деятельнее его (Т.); Я много видел живописных и глухих мест 
в России, но вряд ли когда-нибудь увижу реку более 
девственную и таинственную, чем Пра (Пауст.).

